# Use e-mail confirmation in grails

Tags: email, grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I want to use email confirmation for a user after creating a user. For that I have installed the plugin Email Confirmation 2.0.8. I am using grails 2.3.7 version. And I have done the following attempt although I have no idea about it. But no email is being sent in my yahoo account. Can anyone help me on this please ? Here are my attempts as follows :

in my config file for the plugin >>>

```
plugin.emailConfirmation.from = '"Do not reply" <noreply@mymegacorp.com>'
```

in my view page >>>

```
<g:form controller="userInformation" action="saveUserInfo">
    User E-mail Address : <g:textField name="userEmail" id="userEmail" required=""/>
    <br/>
    <g:submitButton name="submit" id="submit" value="Save User"/>
</g:form>
```

in my controller the action >>>

```
def saveUserInfo() {
    println(params)
    // Send a simple confirmation
    emailConfirmationService.sendConfirmation(
            to:params.userEmail,
            subject:"Please confirm!")
}
```

EDIT ::
here is my new config file >>>

```
    // locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config;
// config files can be ConfigSlurper scripts, Java properties files, or classes
// in the classpath in ConfigSlurper format

// grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

// if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
//    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
// }

grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination

// The ACCEPT header will not be used for content negotiation for user agents containing the following strings (defaults to the 4 major rendering engines)
grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
grails.mime.types = [ // the first one is the default format
    all:           '*/*', // 'all' maps to '*' or the first available format in withFormat
    atom:          'application/atom+xml',
    css:           'text/css',
    csv:           'text/csv',
    form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    js:            'text/javascript',
    json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
    rss:           'application/rss+xml',
    text:          'text/plain',
    hal:           ['application/hal+json','application/hal+xml'],
    xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]

// URL Mapping Cache Max Size, defaults to 5000
//grails.urlmapping.cache.maxsize = 1000

// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/images/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/plugins/**']

// Legacy setting for codec used to encode data with ${}
grails.views.default.codec = "html"

// The default scope for controllers. May be prototype, session or singleton.
// If unspecified, controllers are prototype scoped.
grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'singleton'

// GSP settings
grails {
    views {
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
            codecs {
                expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
                scriptlet = 'html' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
                taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs
                staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
            }
        }
        // escapes all not-encoded output at final stage of outputting
        // filteringCodecForContentType.'text/html' = 'html'
    }
}


grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
// scaffolding templates configuration
grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

// Set to false to use the new Grails 1.2 JSONBuilder in the render method
grails.json.legacy.builder = false
// enabled native2ascii conversion of i18n properties files
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
// packages to include in Spring bean scanning
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
// whether to disable processing of multi part requests
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

// request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

// configure auto-caching of queries by default (if false you can cache individual queries with 'cache: true')
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false

// configure passing transaction's read-only attribute to Hibernate session, queries and criterias
// set "singleSession = false" OSIV mode in hibernate configuration after enabling
grails.hibernate.pass.readonly = false
// configure passing read-only to OSIV session by default, requires "singleSession = false" OSIV mode
grails.hibernate.osiv.readonly = false

environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}

// Email Confirmation configration -- (plugin)
plugin.emailConfirmation.from = '"Do not reply" <noreply@mymegacorp.com>'



// For Mail Plugin Configuration
//grails {
//    mail {
//        host = "smtp.correo.yahoo.es"
//        port = 465
//        username = "bappi_sumon@yahoo.com"
//        password = "password"
//        props = [ "mail.smtp.auth":"true",
//                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
//                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
//                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"  ]
//    }
//}

grails {
    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "pshoikot@gmail.com"
        password = "password"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
}
```

here is my view for send only email not for confirmation >>>

```
<g:form controller="sendMail" action="sendMail">
    <g:submitButton name="submit" value="Send Mail"/>
</g:form>
```

here is my action for sending only email >>>

```
def mailService    

def sendMail() {
        mailService.sendMail {
            to "bappi_sumon@yahoo.com"
            from "bappi_sumon@yahoo.com"
            subject "Hello Bappi"
            body 'this is some text'
        }
    }
```

my view for send confirmation >>>

```
<g:form controller="userInformation" action="saveUserInfo">
    User E-mail Address : <g:textField name="userEmail" id="userEmail" required=""/>
    <br/>
    <g:submitButton name="submit" id="submit" value="Save User"/>
</g:form>
```

my action for send confirmation >>>

```
def emailConfirmationService

def saveUserInfo() {
        println(params)
        // Send a simple confirmation
        emailConfirmationService.sendConfirmation(
                to:params.userEmail,
                subject:"Please confirm!")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check config file and edit host server port number and give username or password.

and you also try Async mail send in grails. for http://fletchermcbeth.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/sending-email-from-grails/

Answer (score 0):

`Email Confirmation plugin` internally using `grails mail plugin` to send mail and for this you have to add the following code in your Config file:

```
plugin.emailConfirmation.from = '"Do not reply" <noreply@mymegacorp.com>'

grails {
  mail {
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 465
    username = "SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
    password = "PASSWORD"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth": "true",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port": "465",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class": "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback": "false"]
  }
}
```

**NOTE:-** Above configurations are for `gmail`. If you want to send mail from `yahoo` then you need to change it slightly, [see mail plugin for configuration for yahoo](http://grails.org/plugin/mail) and other.

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you that you tried for me. But I followed every instruction you suggest me and also in grails mail plugin documentation. But no luck.If I now want to send for confirmation it shows the following error >>> "Error executing tag <p:siteURL>: You cannot read the scheme in non-request rendering operations" and if i want to send only a mail to an account then it shows this error >>> "unable to find valid certification path to requested target". any help please

Comment: I have tried this code and it is working fine. Can you please add your new configuration of your Config file. If you are sending a template or view with the mail please add this as well.

Comment: It is best if you can upload a sample in git.

Comment: sorry its a long file for config, But i never used git for upload that's why i have edited here.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the exception but my application run fine. I have  uploaded my working sample project, have a look. Add the username and password in config file and also add your mail addresses in SendMailController. URL: https://github.com/manishkbharti/EmailConfirmation

Answer (score 0):

For Yahoo...

```
grails {
   mail {
      host = "smtp.correo.yahoo.es"
      port = 465
      username = "myuser"
      password = "mypassword"
      props = [ "mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                       "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                       "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                       "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"  ]
   }
}
```